# Barcode Reader Service for windows

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

I'm developing a software in c# Windows Form, my software must control employees work hours, check-ins and check-outs, I figured i will save these in/outs in a table.Here is the trick, each employee has an unique bar code that is generated after his unique *ID(Social security number, etc.)*, this Bar code prints into  an *ID-CARD* and then gets read by a bar code scanner and through the scanner the event of check-in or out must be handled.

I need to do this without using any type of windows form control, as in, the employees must not interact with the system itself but just the scanner. Can i make a windows service ta handles this automatically and saves it into the database?

My Database is an SQL database.

Comment: Rather depends on the how the scanner is presented to the computer by its driver, E.g. if its a simple keyboard wedge you will just need to capture keystrokes

Comment: Your solution has a design flaw: How do you distinguish between coming and going? In case you expect the sequence come-go-come-go you should consider persons having forgotten to register/'come'.

Comment: the Come and go is handled by a Bit column in the database, its not an issue, i just needed a way to read the code without using a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your time, i ended up making another form for the check ins and outs as a security way to make sure the person checking in/out was the owner of the id card, that's a problem about the barcode design that is not present on any biometric device (i cant give someone my finger so the can go and check me in or out) and the problem ended up being another feature of the software itself.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the design issue of actually keeping track of people, you can do this, I have done it with a warehouse inventory system.

Set up your users with their unique ids in the database, and print out barcode accordingly (lots of free apps for this).  Now set your barcode to tab after each scan, and use an event listener to wait for the tab call.

Once you get that the rest is easy, check against the database, and store the information based on the barcode number, after it does all that it waits for the tab again.  With a cheap scanner you might want to show a screen saying "Okay" or "Try Again"

(with the design issue, you could always make it that an employee can't leave unless that have already signed in, and vice versa, and the screen displaying "sign in, sign out" for if the double scan)

Comment: well tnx for your answer, after all i convinced the client that the best way to capture the check ins and outs and to make sure the person checking its the actual owner of the id card, would be to place a form in readonly fashion on the checking/out module, so that the security guard or whoever is verifying the ckecins cold then report any anormalities in the event that person A checkis with Person B's id card.